# Microsoft Orchestrator, Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell, orchestration

I'm using the following script to access values of a csv file:

```
$csvFile = Import-Csv -path c:\users\myuser\information.csv

$ips=$csvFile.IP

$serverName=$csvFile.Name

$ids = $csvFile.ID
```

When I run this script with Powershell ISE it runs successfully, however, when I run with the activity Run .Net Script in Orchestrator, it returns the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I also tried to check if the file exists through Orchestrator using the Test-Path command and it returns True. So the Orchestrator has access to the file.
The odd part is that this only occurs somethimes.
The same error does not occur when I use the Execute PS Sript activity.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Is that the complete error message??

Comment: Which version of Orchestrator are you using? Which version of Windows does the Orchestrator server run?

Comment: @Theo , yes that is the only error message that it returns.

Comment: @Chris, I'm running in a Windows Server 2019, and using the System Center Orchestrator 2019

Comment: Can you try to run `$PSVersionTable > C:\temp\PSVersionTable.log` in both the "Run .NET Script" and "Execute PS Script" activities and compare the output?

Comment: Both return the same output. What I've also noticed is that this only happens when a runbook is invoked through the task Invoke Runbook. And if I try to write in a file, it says that I don't have the permission to access the file even though I'm admin

Comment: I would expect the PowerShell scripts to run under the service account which has been configued during the Orchestrator installation. It may be needed to adjust the folder NTFS permissions to allow access for the service account.

Comment: Running the script through the "Invoke Runbook" activity should not make a difference.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, I'll look into the service account permissions, maybe that is the problem. Do you know if there is any documentation that I can follow to make sure mys service account has the right permissions?

Comment: Not really, you will need first to have a look at the Windows services (`services.msc`) to find out which service account is configured. Then you will need to go to the folder properties and adjust the permissions to allow proper access to the service account.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll do that and see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Comment out one line at a time, until you find the offending code, only way I found to debug it in Orch. I had to pipe to Out-Null on one of my commands, as I believe it was trying to output to console, which Orch doesn't allow. GL